# How do I add template name to status bar of libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice, uno, libreoffice-basic

Here is a line from the file statusbar.xml from *\share\config\soffice.cfg\modules\swriter\statusbar*

```
<statusbar:statusbaritem xlink:href=".uno:PageStyleName" statusbar:align="left" statusbar:autosize="true" statusbar:width="79"/>
```

I copied the file to user directory: *\config\soffice.cfg\modules\swriter\statusbar*

I just need to display Template Name from document properties. for e.g.
**ThisComponent.getDocumentProperties().TemplateName**

But adding this line does not work as expected. It creates a width of 79 pixels but does not show template name.

```
<statusbar:statusbaritem xlink:href=".uno:ThisComponent.getDocumentProperties().TemplateName" statusbar:align="left" statusbar:autosize="true" statusbar:width="79"/>
```

The purpose is to show current document's template name in status bar just like style name.

---

Update:

I got this code from "Useful Macro Information For OpenOffice.org By Andrew Pitonyak".
It is working as expected. But it does not show any other items on status bar. I need TemplateName next to style name.

```
Function ProgressBar
  ProgressBar = ThisComponent.CurrentController.StatusIndicator
End Function

Sub StatusText()
  Dim sInformation 
  Dim iLen as Integer
  Dim iRest As Integer
  sInformation = ThisComponent.getDocumentProperties().TemplateName
  iLen=Len(sInformation)
  iRest=350-iLen
  ProgressBar.start(sInformation+SPACE(iRest),0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Check this link: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/template-name-not-in-document-properties/41579. Might be the reason that `TemplateName` is not available.

Comment: This is because there is no uno command for this.  any workaround? https://github.com/LibreOffice/help/blob/master/helpers/uno-commands.csv

Comment: I just need to show TemplateName string from this api: 
https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1document_1_1XDocumentProperties.html

Comment: Are you able to display any keywords from getDocuemntProperties(), like Author, Language, CreationDate etc;

Comment: No. I am not able to display anything. I can hide the buttons by removing the relevant lines. But that is not what I need. :(

Comment: Probably `ThisComponent.getDocumentProperties().TemplateName` isn't a valid `uno` command to use in a xml file and I can't find any reference to this online. Its better to get help from the libre community. I think only these commands are allowed to be used here: https://github.com/LibreOffice/help/blob/master/helpers/uno-commands.csv. Sorry couldn't help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

Those are UNO dispatcher commands, not Basic code. It looks like there are only a few that would work, such as `.uno:CharFontName` or `.uno:FrameName`. Most UNO commands perform an action rather than getting information.

At https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10104, there is Basic macro code to set the status indicator:

```vb
ThisComponent.CurrentController.StatusIndicator.Start(vStatusBarText,0)
```

If it's possible to call a macro from statusbar.xml, then the syntax would be like this:

```
xlink:href="vnd.sun.star.script:pythonSamples|TableSample.py$createTable?language=Python&amp;location=share" \
xlink:type="simple"
```

**EDIT**:

Here is a Basic call example, from https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-translate-the-toolbar-into-multiple-languages/42404:

```
xlink:href="vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Module6.gerer_cadre_image1?language=Basic&amp;location=application"
```

Comment: How do I call basic macro instead of python script? Question updated.